# (asm x86) Is there an instruction similar to add, but involving a register and the first value on top of the stack?

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, cpu-registers

For instance, i have EAX with registered value 50. I have a group of other values in the stack (40, 30, 20) i'd like to add to my register. I'm looking for an instruction that puts in EAX the result of 50 + 40 + 30 + 20, without popping the values into another register and then adding them to EAX

Comment: There is no such instruction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean like `add eax, [esp]` / `add eax, [esp+4]` / `add eax, [esp+8]`?

If you want to pop the values after adding them, do `add esp, 12`.

Random access to the stack with normal instructions and addressing modes is straightforward on x86; you don't *have* to use stack instructions like push and pop.

(16-bit mode couldn't use `[sp]` as a base register, but fortunately those dark days are long past.  But even then you could address stack memory relative to `[bp]`, and you usually knew the distance between bp and sp.)